# How to make h3 and <hr> inline, or how to design after the title there will be a horizontal line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make H3 and HR inline, or how to design,just  after the title there will be a horizontal line, in my case it is just hr which is breaking into next line

```
<div class="row">
    <h3 class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-i18n-key="Date.time.location"></h3>
        <hr class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inline both elements, wrap the `h3` and `hr` in separate `div` elements, and move their classes up to their respective `div`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
        <h3 data-i18n-key="Date.time.location">Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make h3 and hr inline by using (display:inline-block) property, but i think below example will help you.

```css
.drawLine{
  position:relative;
}

.drawLine:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; /* line position can be changed according to requirment either top:0, top:50% or bottom:0*/
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:1px;
  background:#ccc;
}

.drawLine span{
  display:inline-block;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:5px; /*space between text and line*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <h3 class="col-xs-12 drawLine"><span data-i18n-key="Date.time.location">your text will be here</span></h3>        
</div>
```